# Can you have an Up, Down, and Change in a single Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have a migration that requires data be converted as there is a schema change and some data needs to be merged. I only need to manually merge it in the up and down functions, but there is also some very repetitive actions in the up and down for changing columns. Is there some way I can have a change function, and perhaps just call it as specific times in the code and it will detect whether or not it's up or down?

Migration is here:
https://gist.github.com/jakecraige/7815478

Thanks

Comment: Migrations are one-offs, I wouldn't waste time or effort making them pretty, just make them reliable and functional.

Comment: While that's true, this is more for future reference because it could save me time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. And more of it: you can make your code much prettier:

```
def change
  # Here we putting reversible part of our migration
  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up do
      # code that performs irreversible part of migration
    end
    dir.down do
      # code that performs irreversible part of rollback
    end
  end
end
```